# Program with multiple ampersand works fine

Tags: rust

The following program works fine:

```
pub fn foo(_v: &str) -> bool {
    false
}

fn main() {
    let f = "hello world";
    println!("{}", foo(&&&&f)); // note the number of & here
}
```

In fact it works on passing any number of `&`. How should I interpret what is going on ?

My rust version:

```
$ rustc --version
rustc 1.32.0-nightly (13dab66a6 2018-11-05)
```

Comment: Also TRPL says this: `When the Deref trait is defined for the types involved, Rust will analyze the types and use Deref::deref as many times as necessary to get a reference to match the parameter’s type.`

Comment: I don't think the duplicate target is appropriate. That question is about auto-dereferencing (which only happens for a method receiver); this question is about `Deref` coercion (which can happen at any coercion site).

Comment: I think that `autoderef` applies also in the `function(&&&&&x)` case, not only in the context of methods receivers. 
In this case I could agree with tagging this question as duplicate, but @trentcl expresses another point of view. Some more consideration for helping to clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods):

> Deref coercion is a convenience that Rust performs on arguments to
>   functions and methods. Deref coercion converts a reference to a type
>   that implements Deref into a reference to a type that Deref can
>   convert the original type into. Deref coercion happens automatically
>   when we pass a reference to a particular type’s value as an argument
>   to a function or method that doesn’t match the parameter type in the
>   function or method definition. A sequence of calls to the deref method
>   converts the type we provided into the type the parameter needs.

So basically, in function arguments the compiler will automatically remove any `&` written or implied until it gets to a type that can be passed to the function.

Answer (score 5):

Because the compiler automatically dereferences the chain of references, you can imagine that it inserts as many `*` as necessary to get the right type:

```
foo(&&&f)
```

is converted to:

```
foo(&****(&&&f))
```

that leads to the right invocation:

```
foo(f)
```

The insertions of as many `*` as needed is actually performed by [this blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/deref.rs.html#86-90) of `Deref` trait:

```
impl<'a, T: ?Sized> Deref for &'a T {
    type Target = T;

    fn deref(&self) -> &T { *self }
}
```

**Note**: I've update my answer because in the original I used the term `autoderef` in the wrong way, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion) for details.

Comment: I've added a note to my answer, i'm hope it clarifies what I'm saying