# What is the relation between auto-dereferencing and deref coercion?

Tags: rust, terminology, dereference

After some [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53294663/program-with-multiple-ampersand-works-fine), I'm now a little bit confused about the relation between `auto-dereferencing` and `deref coercion`.

[It seems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28519997/what-are-rusts-exact-auto-dereferencing-rules) that the term "auto-dereferencing" applies only when the target to dereference is a method receiver,
whereas [it seems](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) that the term "deref coercion" applies to function arguments and all contexts it needs to.

I thought that a dereference does not always involve deref coercion, but  I'm not sure: does dereferencing always use some `Deref::deref` trait implementation?

If so, is the implementor of `T: Deref<Target = U> where T: &U` built into the compiler?

Finally, it sounds natural to use the term "autoderef" in all the cases where the compiler implicitly transforms `&&&&x` to `&x`:

```
pub fn foo(_v: &str) -> bool {
    false
}

let x="hello world";
foo(&&&&x);
```

Is this the general consensus of the community?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The parallels between the two cases are rather superficial.

In a method call expression, the compiler first needs to determine which method to call. This decision is based on the type of the receiver. The compiler builds a list of candidate receiver types, which include all types obtained by repeatedly derefencing the receiver, but also `&T` and `&mut T` for all types `T` encountered. This is the reason why you can call a method receiving `&mut self` directly as `x.foo()` instead of having to write `(&mut x).foo()`. For each type in the candidate list, the compiler then looks up inherent methods and methods on visible traits. See the [language reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.26.1/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) for further details.

A deref coercion is rather different. It only occurs at a *coercion site* where the compiler exactly knows what type to expect. If the actual type encountered is different from the expected type, the compiler can use any coercion, including a deref coercion, to convert the actual type to the expected type. The list of possible coercions includes unsized coercions, pointer weakening and deref coercions. See the the [chapter on coercions in the Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/coercions.html) for further details.

So these are really two quite different mechanisms – one for finding the right method, and one for converting types when it is already known what type exactly to expect. The first mechanism also automatically *references* the receiver, which can never happen in a coercion.

> I thought that a dereference does not always involve deref coercion, but I'm not sure: does dereferencing always use some `Deref::deref` trait implementation?

Not every dereferencing is a deref coercion. If you write `*x`, you *explicitly* dereference `x`. A deref *coercion* in contrast is performed implicitly by the compiler, and only in places where the compiler knows the expected type.

The [semantics of dereferencing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator) depend on whether the type of `x` is a *pointer type*, i.e. a reference or a raw pointer, or not. For pointer types, `*x` denotes the object `x` points to, while for other types `*x` is equivalent to `*Deref::deref(&x)` (or the mutable anlogue of this).

> If so, is the implementor of `T: Deref<Target = U> where T: &U` built into the compiler?

I'm not quite sure what your syntax is supposed to mean – it's certainly not valid Rust syntax – but I guess you are asking whether derefencing an instance of `&T` to `T` is built into the compiler. As mentioned above, dereferencing of pointer types, including references, is built into the compiler, but there is also a [blanket implementation of `Deref` for `&T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/src/core/ops/deref.rs.html#86-90) in the standard library. This blanket implementation is useful for generic code – the trait bound `T: Deref<Target = U>` otherwise wouldn't allow for `T = &U`.

Comment: I think the point is in the last sentence. Rephrasing my question: the semantic of dereferencing known by the compiler may be called auto-dereferencing? 

At coercion site there is more then a `deref coercion` mechanisms, because, as you pointed out, the defer blanket impl `fn deref(&self) -> &T { *self }` is idempotent and it does not explain &&&&x  -> &x.

Comment: @attdona I can't follow. Auto-dereferencing means implicit rather than explicit dereferencing. It has nothing to do with the semantics of dereferencing. I also can't make sense of the word "idempotent" in this context. A function can only be idempotent when the range is a subset of the domain, which isn't the case here - the function maps values of type `&&T` to values of type `&T`.

Comment: I used the term idempotent inappropriately to signify that the deref blanket implementation transforms a &T in a &T.

Clearly if we apply `deref()` to a `&&T`, or a `&&&T` we got a `&T`, but in this case the main actor I see in action is auto-deref.
After the auto-deref of the `&&&x.deref()` receiver, `deref()` returns a `&T` from a `&T`: a sort of do-nothing operation (I assume `deref` it is called because the docs states that `deref` is always called but to me it seems useless in this case).
Which term best describe what is happening: auto-deref or deref coercion?

Comment: @attdona I'm sorry, I still can't follow. The prototype of the blanket deref implementation is essentially `deref(&&T) -> &T`, while you appear to think it's `deref(&T) -> &T`. I may have misread your comment though.

Comment: Many Thanks for your patience!. I wrongly thought blanket impl as `deref(&T) -> &T` and this make me write non-sense comments.

Comment: Could someone explain why the [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/deref.rs.html#79-86) of `Deref` for &T maps &&T to &T. `fn deref(&self) -> &T` , the &T is returned from the `deref` function. The Deref is impled for &T, and the return is &T, so how it map &&T to &T? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Joey The `self` argument has type `&Self`, and `Self` is `&T`, so `&Self` is `&&T`. The return type of `deref()` is obviously `&T`, so the function maps from `&&T` to `&T`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks a lot. Very clear explanation.