# Why is the compiler letting me borrow another borrow in a box?

Tags: rust, borrowing

I'm wondering if someone can help me understand why this program behaves as it does:

```
fn main() { 
    let mut x = 456; 
    { 
        let mut y = Box::new(&x); 
        y = Box::new(&mut y); 
        println!("GOT {}",*y);
    } 
}
```

This program compiles under rust 1.35.0 (both 2015 and 2018 editions), and prints

```
GOT 456
```

But, I'm confused what's going on here.  I'm guessing that this is an example of an *auto-dereference*.  So, in reality, it looks like this:

```
fn main() { 
    let mut x = 456; 
    { 
        let mut y = Box::new(&x); 
        y = Box::new(&mut *y); 
        println!("GOT {}",*y);
    } 
}
```

Is that it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a case of [*deref coercion*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion), but one that is obfuscated by a few other unnecessary parts of the code. The following improvements should be made here:

1. The `mut` modifier on variable `x` is not needed because it is never modified.
2. The borrow of `y` in `Box::new(&mut y)` does not have to be mutable because the variable holds an immutable reference.
3. The `println!` implementation also knows to print values behind references, so the explicit `*` is not needed.

Then, we get the following code:

```rust
fn main() { 
    let x = 456; 
    { 
        let mut y = Box::new(&x); 
        y = Box::new(&y); 
        println!("GOT {}", y);
    } 
}
```

`y` is a variable of type `Box<&i32>` which is initially bound to a box created in the outer scope. The subsequent assignment to a new box works because the `&y`, of type `&Box<&i32>`, is coerced to `&&i32`, which can then be put in the box by automatically dereferencing the first borrow. This coercion is required because the variable `x` can only be assigned values of the same `Box<&i32>` type.

The lifetime of the reference inside both boxes also ended up being the same, because they refer to the same value in `x`.

See also:

- [What is the relation between auto-dereferencing and deref coercion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion)