# What is the difference between * and the deref method?

Tags: rust

For example, I have a struct with Deref implemented

```rust
use std::ops::{Deref, DerefMut, IndexMut};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Selector<T> {
    elements: Vec<T>,
    current: usize
}

impl<T> Deref for Selector<T> {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T {
        &self.elements[self.current]
    }
}

impl<T> DerefMut for Selector<T> {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T {
        &mut self.elements[self.current]
    }
}
```

Then I do `*s = 'w';`
This means that rust is doing `&s.elements[s.current] = 'w'`
which is the same as `s.elements.index_mut(s.current) = 'w';`
except index_mut returns a reference and you can't assign a reference to something so I changed the above to `*&mut *s.elements.index_mut(s.current) = 'w';`

So `*s` is the same as `*s.deref_mut()` where deref_mut is my implementation of Deref. So this leads me to think that `*s` is more like `**s`, where the first `*` calls my deref_mut method and the second `*` turns the resulting `&mut T` into `mut T`. Is rust adding another deref method after my implementation of Deref because deref_mut returns a reference? If so what is this called?

Does this mean that `*` and the deref method are different where one follows a pointer to data and the other one allows you to do something to a reference and then return another reference? Is rust implicitly inserting another `*` to convert the reference?

Comment: Why does your code call `index_mut` directly? `&mut self.elements[self.current]` works fine.

Comment: What is the type of `s`? If `s: Selector<T>`, then `**s` will not compile.

Comment: i accidentally put the wrong code, `&mut self.elements[self.current]` is better

Comment: I am just using `**s` as an example to illustrate my thoughts. Of course it won't compile but I am asking if rust is using two deref_muts,  one to call my deref_mut method and the other to turn the resulting `&mut T ` into `mut T`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819

Answer (score 1):

If `x` has type `&T` or `&mut T`, then `*x` has type `T`.

What if `x` has some other type `S`? If `S` implements `Deref` or `DerefMut`, then Rust will call `.deref()` or `.deref_mut()` on `x`, and dereference that.

> Does this mean that * and the deref method are different where one follows a pointer to data and the other one allows you to do something to a reference and then return another reference?

Yes. The unary `*` operator follows a reference, and the deref traits coerce a non-reference into a reference.

Comment: When I do `*s` the first `* `calls my deref_mut method but rust has to convert the `&mut T ` that deref_mut returned to `T` like you said. Does this mean rust is inserting another `* ` after turning the first `*` into my deref_mut to convert the reference?  I only used one *` when I did `*s` so I am asking if rust implicitly inserts another `*`.

Comment: No, it does not insert another `*`. The `deref_mut` method converts `&mut Selector<T>` to `&mut T`, and the `*` operator converts `&mut T` to `T`.