# Why is there no deref coercion from &String to &str when calling From::from?

Tags: rust, dereference, coercion

Usually I can use an `&String` in any function call that accepts an `&str`, I believe this is because `String` implements  `Deref<Target = str>`.

In the following case using `From` it does not work:

```rust
struct Foo;

impl From<&str> for Foo {
    fn from(_: &str) -> Foo {
        unimplemented!()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::new();
    Foo::from(&s);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61972f3aa91daf33d4a18db353f2ecb0)

Yields:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `Foo: From<&String>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |     Foo::from(&s);
   |     ^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<&String>` is not implemented for `Foo`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <Foo as From<&str>>
   = note: required by `from`
```

Why do I not get the `Deref` I am used to in this case?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [What is the relation between auto-dereferencing and deref coercion?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53341819/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: ahh TY @Shepmaster that's indeed the post I'm looking for. It also explains why doing a fully qualified ```<Foo as From<&str>>::from(&s);``` works.