# Trouble understanding &mut &mut reference

Tags: rust

I'm following [this](https://learn.figment.io/tutorials/create-a-fullstack-mail-dapp-on-solana) tutorial and I'm having trouble understanding the following code:

```
mail_account.serialize(&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..])?;
```

where `mail_account` is a struct and `.serialize()` is a method derived from [Borsh Serialize](https://docs.rs/borsh/0.7.1/borsh/ser/trait.BorshSerialize.html).

One other thing to note is that `account` is an [AccountInfo](https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.8.1/solana_program/account_info/struct.AccountInfo.html) struct from the solana_program crate and `data` has type: `Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [u8]>>`

The author explains the code as follows:

> You might notice the tricky `&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..]` expression. The `serialize()` method takes a reference to a mutable slice of `u8` as an argument, the `borrow_mut()` method returns a `RefMut`. We can't pass `RefMut` to a method that expects a slice, so we take a mutable slice of `RefMut` which returns a mutable slice of `u8`

What I do understand is that we want to write the current `mail_account` struct into `account.data`, which is why we are borrowing a mutable reference to `account.data`. What I don't understand is why is it important to add the `[..]`? I assume it has something to do with the `serialize()` expecting a slice.

I'm also having trouble understanding how adding `&mut &mut` to `account.data.borrow_mut()[..]` creates a slice of `u8`. How is this being converted to `u8`? To me it seems like it would just be adding additional mutable references to the original one. (How is the type changing from `RefMut` to `&[u32]`?)

Comment: Pretty sure `&mut *account.data.borrow_mut()` would work.

Comment: @IbraheemAhmed Could you explain your logic behind that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I guess, you have multiple questions:

1. > What I don't understand is why is it important to add the [..]?
2. > I'm also having trouble understanding how adding &mut &mut to account.data.borrow_mut()[..] creates a slice of u8. How is this being converted to u8?

Those questions are kinda intertwined, as you can see inthe anwser to question 1.

## Question 1

When we look at the [documentation about certain cases of indexing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html), we see, that

```rust
account.data.borrow_mut()[..]
```

is sugar for

```rust
*(account.data.borrow_mut().index_mut(..))
```

Why is that a valid expression?

`..` is a shorthand for [`RangeFull`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html).

`RangeFull` has an implementation for [`SliceIndex<[u8]>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/struct.RangeFull.html#impl-SliceIndex%3C%5BT%5D%3E).

With this [blanket implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.IndexMut.html#impl-IndexMut%3CI%3E-1) we get a `IndexMut<RangeFull> for [u8]`, which provides

```rust
fn index_mut(&mut [u8], index: RangeFull) -> &mut [u8]
```

Now <s>the [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch15-02-deref.html?highlight=deref#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) and or</s> the [auto dereferencing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html) mentioned in other <s>answers and</s> comments kicks in.

```rust
account.data.borrow_mut().index_mut(..)
```

And `RefMut<&mut [u8]>` implements [`DerefMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.DerefMut.html#impl-DerefMut-4) which has `Deref<Target = &mut [u8]>` as a super trait.

And `&mut [u8]` implements `DerefMut` with `Deref<Target = [u8]>` as super trait.

As mentioned in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/method-call-expr.html), the compiler will now take the receiver expression and dereference it repeatedly, so it gets a list of candidate types. It also adds for each type resulting from a dereference the reference type and the mutable reference type to the list of candidate types. From this candidate types it selects one providing the method to call.

1. `RefMut<&mut [u8]>` using `account.data.borrow_mut()`
2. `&RefMut<&mut [u8]>`
3. `&mut RefMut<&mut [u8]>`
4. `&mut [u8]` using `*account.data.borrow_mut().deref_mut()`
5. `&&mut [u8]`
6. `&mut &mut [u8]`
7. `[u8]` using `*(*account.data.borrow_mut().deref_mut())`
8. `&[u8]`
9. `&mut [u8]`

(In 7. we are dereferencing a pointer type `&mut [u8]` so no `DerefMut` Trait is used.)

The first (and only) type in this list providing an `index_mut()` method is `&mut [u8]`, via the `IndexMut<FullRange>` implementation for `[u8]`, so `&mut [u8]` is selected as receiver type. The return type of `index_mut()` is `&mut [u8]` as well.

So now, we hopefully understand, the type of

`*(account.data.borrow_mut().index_mut(..))` is `[u8]`.

Hence:

## Question 2

```rust
&mut &mut account.data.borrow_mut()[..]
```

has type `&mut &mut [u8]`.

## Addendum

`&mut &mut [u8]` is needed as `&mut [u8]` has a [`Write`](https://docs.rs/borsh/0.9.1/borsh/maybestd/io/trait.Write.html)
implementation.

And [`serialize`](https://docs.rs/borsh/0.9.1/borsh/ser/trait.BorshSerialize.html#tymethod.serialize)

```
pub fn serialize<W: Write>(&self, writer: &mut W) -> Result<()>
```

needs an argument of type `&mut W`, where `W` implements `Write`.

The reference to a value of type `W` implementing `Write` needs to mutable, as we want to keep track of the actual writing position in the value of type `W`. In the case of `&mut [u8]` we simply alter the reference to start at a different position in the underlying slice, so we need a mutable reference to the mutable reference, as we want to alter the mutable reference itself and not only the underlying data.

## Addendum 2

Just use

```rust
mail_account.serialize(&mut *account.data.borrow_mut())?;
```

Comment: In the auto dereferencing section for 4. isn't `*account...` dereferencing and then we're also dereferencing again with `...().deref_mut()`? Why isn't it just one dereference to go from `RefMut<&mut [u8]>` to `&mut [u8]`? I tried printing the types of `account.data.borrow_mut().deref_mut()` and `*account.data.borrow_mut().deref_mut()` to understand but encounter `deref_mut() not found in RefMut<'_, &mut [u8]>` for both expressions.

Comment: Oops I wasn't using `std::ops::DerefMut` and also learnt that `deref_mut()` is actually just returning another reference. Now I get as `&mut &mut [u8]` for `account.data.borrow_mut().deref_mut()` which I understand as a mutable reference to the mutable reference for the slice. I'm running into an ownership error when I try `*account.data.borrow_mut().deref_mut()`: `Cannot move out of a mutable reference. move occurs because value has type &mut [u8]`.

Comment: As you can see in the [reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator) for non pointer types `*v` is simply `*std::ops::DerefMut::deref_mut(&mut v)`. So dereferencing implies using `deref_mut` but still apply the dereferencing operator `*` to the result. And `RefMut<_>` is a non pointer type to start with.

Comment: `let t = *something;` for a something of type `&mut T` would mean we try to get ownership (not just a borrow) for the value referenced by `something`. (Unless `T` implements `Copy`.) You can use `*something` to assign values to and call methods or maybe also other stuff, but you can't move the value out of it.

Answer (score 1):

This magic is called *type coercion*. You can read about it [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion) or [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-coercions.html). Basically what happens is an implicit conversion of `Rc<RefCell<&'a mut [u8]>>` into `&mut [u8]`. The way Rust does it is as following:

1. Auto-dereference when use `.` operator - Rc<RefCell<...> is dereferenced into `RefCell<>` when you call `.borrow_mut()`.
2. `borrow_mut` returns a value of type `RefMut<T>`, which implements trait `DerefMut<T>`.
3. The method `.serialize` takes `&mut [u8]` as argument, so you cannot call it with just `&mut data.borrow_mut()` as it has the type of `&mut RefMut<&mut [u8]>`.
4. Adding additional `&mut` before RefMut allows Rust compiler to use the type coercion. Seeing the type `&mut &mut RefMut<&mut [u8]>` it can automatically convert inner `&mut RefMut<T>` into just `&mut T`, so you get `&mut &mut &mut [u8]`. Then it can repeat the process twice, each time turning `&mut &mut` into `&mut`. So in the end you get `&mut [u8]`.

The more explicit way to do the same thing is to derefrence `RefMut`:

```
&mut *account.data.borrow_mut()
```

It does the same thing but directly.

Comment: No, there is not deref coercion happening here. It's rather auto-dereferencing as part of method lookup, [which is a distinct mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344847/279627).

Comment: The method `.serialize()` does not accept an `&mut [u8]`. It rather accepts an `&mut W` with `W` implementing the `Write` trait. The trait is implemented for `&mut [u8]`, so to pass in an `&mut W`, you actually need `&mut &mut [u8]`. (The `serialize()` method _should_ simply accept a `W` instead.)

Comment: The additional `&mut` is completely unrelated to any type coercion, not least because there isn't any type coercion happening here.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thank for the pointer to auto-dereferencing, so I could rework my bit of handwaving.