# Rust: How to use methods defined in traits within newly spawned threads using Arc?

Tags: rust

So I am trying to define a method in a trait that would spawn a thread and make use of another trait method, but I am a bit stuck on how to "unpack" it from Arc<...>:

```
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::sync::Mutex;
use websocket::{Message, WebSocketResult};


trait Sender<S>
where
    S: Into<Message<'static>> + Send,
{
    fn send_once(&mut self, message: S) -> WebSocketResult<()>;
    fn send_in_thread(&mut self, sleep_interval: time::Duration) -> WebSocketResult<()> {
        let self_copy = Arc::new(Mutex::new(self)).clone();
        let thread_join_handle = thread::spawn(move || self_copy.send_once(message));
        thread_join_handle.join().unwrap()
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
no method named `send_once` found for struct `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<&mut Self>>` in the current scope

method not found in `std::sync::Arc<std::sync::Mutex<&mut Self>>`
```

Which is fair, I didn't define such a method on this wrapper type, but how do I get out of this situation the shortest way? Or, the most idiomatic way? I used Arc because previously I had `Self cannot be sent between threads safely` if I didn't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here:

`Arc<T>` is used to provide "shared ownership". By default, a value has a single owner, which ensures that each value is dropped exactly once. If the same piece of data could be owned by 2 variables, it would be dropped twice. An `Arc` bypasses this restriction by providing a different `Drop` implementation: "if there are other references, decrease the reference count by one, otherwise, drop the wrapped data".

`Arc` dereferences to `T` via the `Deref` trait. This means that something like the following will work:

```rust
let string = Arc::new("hello");
println!("{}", string.len());
```

Note there is no "unpacking" needed, this happens implicitly, and is explained in some detail in this question: [What is the relation between auto-dereferencing and deref coercion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion)

`Mutex` does a different job. It allows an otherwise non-thread-safe value to be shared safely between threads, by performing "locking" to prevent simultaneous reads/writes.

Because of this, if you have a `Mutex<i32>`, you can't just treat that as an `i32`, you first have to acquire the lock, by calling `.lock()`, and then handle the `Result` you get back in case the mutex was poisoned.

TLDR:
use `self_copy.lock().unwrap().send_once()`, or `.lock()` and handle the error case

Answer (score 1):

You need to lock the mutex to obtain a [`MutexGuard`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.MutexGuard.html) before you can call methods on it:

```rust
let thread_join_handle = thread::spawn(move || self_copy
    .lock()
    .unwrap()
    .send_once(message));
```