# Why can I pass a parameter of &&str to a function requires &str?

Tags: rust

I am doing [rustlings](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings) exercises. Here are my answer for `iterator2.rs`:

```
// Step 1.
// Complete the `capitalize_first` function.
// "hello" -> "Hello"
pub fn capitalize_first(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut c = input.chars();
    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(first) => first.to_uppercase().to_string() + c.as_str()
    }
}

// Step 2.
// Apply the `capitalize_first` function to a slice of string slices.
// Return a vector of strings.
// ["hello", "world"] -> ["Hello", "World"]
pub fn capitalize_words_vector(words: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    words.iter().map(|w| {capitalize_first(w)}).collect()
}
```

The `capitalize_first()` function requires a `&str` argument, but the type of parameter `w` in the closure of `map()` is `&&str` (inferred by Clion). The compiler doesn't complain anything and I can pass the exercise. So what's going on behind the scene?

[image: type inferred by Clion]

Comment: Rust performs automatic [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#implicit-deref-coercions-with-functions-and-methods) on arguments.

Comment: Another relevant question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion