# Find all substring indices in string

Tags: rust, ownership

I am very new to rust, (still working my way through the book) and am re-writing a DNA searching algorithm I wrote in node.js in rust. Each error I've gotten so far I've been able to get through except this one. I am trying to write a function that takes a DNA sequence and a 3-letter flag, and returns all indexes where that flag is found in the input sequence.

```
fn get_termination_flag_indices (input_sequence: String, flag: String) -> Vec<(usize, &'static str)> {
let flag_indices: Vec<_> = input_sequence.match_indices(&flag).into_iter().collect();

println!("{:?}", flag_indices);
flag_indices
}
```

I haven't been able to make sense of the error I'm receiving:

```
returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

I understand from a very high level what it's telling me, but I don't know how to fix it. Honestly I'm just not far enough along to really grasp what's going on here. Any help explaining what's going on under the hood would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Have you read the [Understanding Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html) chapter?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full error message, including the compiler explanations and suggestions. In particular you say that your function returns the indexes where the flag is found, which should be `Vec<usize>`, but you appear to also be returning string slices in addition to the indexes.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, when using Rust without a good understanding of lifetimes, it's best to avoid references in return values and structs. Where necessary, cloning is easy. (And in this case, `Vec<usize>` should indeed be enough, as all the returned `&str`s should be equal.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would solve it (you could make `flag` a `&str` to make it even better but it is not required to solve the error):

```rust
fn get_termination_flag_indices (input_sequence: &str, flag: String) -> Vec<(usize, &str)> {
    let flag_indices: Vec<_> = input_sequence.match_indices(&flag).into_iter().collect();
    
    println!("{:?}", flag_indices);

    flag_indices
}
```

#### Here is what I think caused the error:

Unfortunately, I don't know enough to say for certain but here goes:

When calling `match_indices`, a reference of `input_sequence` is created under the hood (`match_indices` takes a reference to `self`). Let's give it a lifetime of `'a`

Later, the `&str` that `flag_indices` collects, has that same lifetime `'a`. The problem is that as soon as the function returns with `flag_indices`, the reference that was created inside the function (with lifetime `'a`) is dropped as well. So the `flag_indices` now contains references that were dropped.

Comment: You explanation is quite right, here's some details: `input_sequences` is [auto-(de)referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53344847/401059) into `&'a str` when calling [`match_indices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.match_indices). This returns a `MatchIndices<'a, …>`, which implements [`Iterator<Item = (usize, &'a str)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/struct.MatchIndices.html#associatedtype.Item).

Comment: That was it. I believe I need to dig deeper into lifetimes in relation to ownership. Thanks!