# why == operator requires dereference while eq does not

Tags: rust

I'm still new to rust and I'm a bit puzzled by this tiny detail below. From what I understood so far is that `==` and `eq()` are pretty much equivalent. I wonder why is dereferencing `y` required for the operator version but not for the function call. I was expecting that no dereferencing should be required at all since the `eq` method expects a reference to `y` anyways.

```
use std::cmp::{Eq, PartialEq};
struct X{}
struct Y {}
impl PartialEq<Y> for X{
    fn eq(&self, rhs: &Y)->bool{
        true
    }
}

impl PartialEq for X{
    fn eq(&self, rhs: &X)->bool{
        true
    }
}

impl Eq for X {}

fn main() {
    let x = X{};
    let y = Y{};
    
    let f1 = |y: &Y| x == *y;
    let f2 = |y: &Y| x.eq(y);
    
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ca8949829b348afb8323f72920392f31)

Comment: Because the `eq()` method takes a reference for the parameter `rhs`. In other words: you pass a *reference* to `eq()`, so if you already have a reference you'll not need to dereference it.

Comment: Also because Rust will autoref (and autoderef) the subject of a method call, but not operators. And since `PartialEq` is defined in terms of `X` and `Y` that's what Rust wants. OP can implement `PartialEq<&Y> for X` and now the first lambda will compile but the second won't.

Comment: @Jesper I'm very convinced about that part. I even stated clearly that I consider this the expected behavior.  My problem is what I understand is that `==`  and `eq` are equivalent so I do not expect to have to deref for `==` for the same reason that you stated in your comment.

Comment: @Masklinn are there any references to this discrepancy between operators and function calls?

Comment: Not directly about the discrepancy. But [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion/53344847#53344847) explains the machinery that is invoked for function calls (which simply isn't there for operators).

Answer (score 3):

Because `eq()` and `==` are *not* equivalent.

Even without [autoref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion/53344847#53344847), when you call `a == b`, Rust *does not* execute `PartialEq::eq(a, b)`. Rather, it executes `PartialEq::eq(&a, &b)`. That is, Rust calls `eq()` with automatically-referenced operands when using the operator.

So, `x == *y` is basically `(&x).eq(&*y)`, but `x == y` is `(&x).eq(&y)`, which uses a double reference for `y` and therefore doesn't work.

When you write `x.eq(y)`, however, Rust does not perform any adjustment to `y` (well, almost), but it does borrow `x` because of autoref. So this is the same as `(&x).eq(y)`, which is the same as the operator version `(&x).eq(&*y)`.