# Does the compiler make dereference mutable reference and then re-reference when passed to a function with a reference parameter?

Tags: rust

Let's say I have such a function:

```
fn take_by_ref(i:&i32){
    println!("{}",i);
}
```

Now I want to pass mutable reference there:

```
#[test]
fn test_mut(){
    let mut x = 9;
    let m = &mut x;
}
```

And it is unclear what is the difference between the two calls to this function?

first:

```
take_by_ref(m);
```

second:

```
take_by_ref(&*m);
```

Are these two calls equal and the compiler makes *first* call as the *second* one automatically? or is there a difference?
And won't the rule that either mut reference or immutable can exist be violated here when call `take_by_ref`?

That is, the question is that when passing a `mut` variable to such a function, it can become auto-immutable?

Comment: Or maybe this one? [What is the relation between auto dereferencing and deref coercion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53341819/what-is-the-relation-between-auto-dereferencing-and-deref-coercion)

Comment: @cafce25 Where do you see auto-dereferencing here?

Comment: TL;DR - yes, `take_by_ref(m)` is semantically the same as `take_by_ref(&*m)` due to deref coercion.